# Non-US Patreon/YouTube alternative?

Tags: video, online-payment

American companies like YouTube or Patreon are now required to collect [taxes](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/10391362?hl=en&authuser=1) from me, a video creator. I need a website that feature a service like the "Join" button on YouTube where customers don't watch videos unless they pay. I need this website to be located outside of the USA so that the tax doesn't apply. Any recommendations?

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by the "join" button functionality in this case?

Comment: @bad_coder When they press the button, they pay so that they can unlock and watch the videos.

Comment: Tax always applies in the country you live, whether or not it does in the country hosting.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's okay to pay reasonable taxes in the country I live because I get some benefits too. But I don't want to pay taxes to other counties like the USA (with all due respect). Google informed me that they can withhold 30% of my earnings for taxes because it's a US company. So I'm looking for a Non-US company so that I don't pay 30% of what I earn. It's too much!